# Nodejs: Huge performance difference among UUID in normal string, base64 string and Buffer comparison

Tags: node.js, string, base64, buffer

Result:

```
true
base64: 35.758ms
true
string: 12.811ms
true
buffer: 127.691ms
```

Code:

```
let n = 1000000;

let uuid = require("node-uuid");

let uuidaString = uuid.v4(),
    uuidbString = uuidaString.slice(0),

    uuidaBuffer = uuid.parse(uuidaString, new Buffer(16)),
    uuidbBuffer = uuid.parse(uuidbString, new Buffer(16)),

    uuidaBase64 = uuidaBuffer.toString("base64"),
    uuidbBase64 = uuidbBuffer.toString("base64");

console.log(uuidaBase64 === uuidbBase64);
console.time("base64");
for (let i = 0; i < n && uuidaBase64 === uuidbBase64; i++) {

}
console.timeEnd("base64");

console.log(uuidaString === uuidbString);
console.time("string");
for (let i = 0; i < n && uuidaString === uuidbString; i++) {

}
console.timeEnd("string");


console.log(Buffer.compare(uuidaBuffer, uuidbBuffer) === 0);
console.time("buffer");
for (let i = 0; i < n && Buffer.compare(uuidaBuffer, uuidbBuffer) === 0; i++) {

}
console.timeEnd("buffer");
```

Does anybody explain the result? I would expect normal string comparison would be the slowest but it shows the fastest. Other than that I would expect base64 string comparison would be faster than normal string comparison because base64 string is shorter than normal string. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this instead:

```
uuidbBase64 = uuidaBase64.slice(0)
```

When I do that, I see nearly identical times for regular strings versus base64 strings.

Perhaps `.slice(0)` just returns the same object, so it doesn't have to be compared character by character?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp  The slice() method returns the selected elements in an array, as a new array object.

Comment: We're not calling array slice, we're calling string slice: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp.

Comment: In any case, I used "perhaps" and a question mark because I don't actually *know* why the `.slice(0)` version makes for a quick comparison. I'm just hypothesizing. You can use `.split('').join('')` instead (in both cases) to get a slower comparison.

Comment: BTW, with the slow version (using `.split('').join('')`), I see the base64 string comparison being considerably faster than comparing the longer strings.

Comment: I think you are correct. This also proves string.slice(0) returns the same reference